# char array has some garbage after first loop in c

Tags: c, arrays

[image]

```
    while( (entry = readdir(dir_pointer)) != NULL)
        {
                char *fullpath = malloc(dir_len + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);
                printf("\nfullpath: %s\n", fullpath);
                strcat(fullpath, dir);  // concatenate file directory;
                printf("\ndir: %s\n",fullpath);
                strcat(fullpath, "/");  // concatenate "/";
                strcat(fullpath, entry->d_name);    // concatenate filename;
                printf("\nfullpath: %s\n", fullpath);   // print to check;

                free(fullpath);
                // close the file;



        }
```

From the output, the first round of while loop works fine, the file full path is correct;

However, for the second round, the file full path contains some garbage,

Where does the garbage come from?

How to solve this, I have tried the memset() but it didn't work.

Comment: You call `strcat()` to append to a newly `malloc()`ed, uninitialised array... this will only work as you seem to expect if it happens to start with a null byte (which is not at all guaranteed).

Comment: Easy fix would be to change that first `strcat()` to a `strcpy()` (and also get rid of the `printf()` right before it which tries to print that uninitialised string)

Comment: @Dmitri In fact, none of the above: `snprintf()`.

Comment: @iharob `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` would probably be better, but the `strcpy()` fix is a much smaller change.

Comment: @Dmitri Agree, except that there is no reason to use `sprintf()` when you have `snprintf()`.

Comment: @iharob Only that `snprintf()` will check the length as it goes, which is not necessary when you've already ensured that the buffer length is adequate... but yes, `snprintf()` is a safer choice to make a habit of.

Comment: Using `snprintf()` without checking results trades one problem (buffer overrun) with incorrect shortened-string.  Use an adequate buffer (see `MAXPATH`) or use `snprintf()` and check its results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fullpath` is not initialized. You should not use and you don't need to use `strcat()` in this situation, but if you want it to work simply make the first parameter of `strcat()` a valid string, it can be an empty string.

Right after `malloc()`

```
if (fullpath == NULL)
    exit(-1);
fullpath[0] = '\0';
```

after that, you can use `fullpath` as the first parameter to `strcat()`.

You see, `strcat()` is bad to use because it scans the first paramter checking for the `null` terminator but, in your case the contents of  `fullpath` are undeterminate and it might happen that the first character is a `'\0'` but there is no guarantee.

You can see how, searching for the `'\0'` terminator every time you pass the string to `strcat()` which is presumably growing will be inefficient.

Also, since you are going to `free()` `fullpath` inside the loop, don't use `malloc()` at all. You can use a VLA (*Variable length array*) or a fixed length one too. Calling `malloc()` and `free()` is not cheap and you will already need `strcpy()` or better `snprintf()` in this case is more suitable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, and also the extra advise.